How to apply Bottom Right inner shadow to ImageView in android?
I'm trying to add inner shadow effect in my ImageView as shown in the below image:

My imageView is inside a cardview with some other layouts
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="0dp">

                    <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:contentDescription="image"
                        android:maxHeight="400dp"
                        android:minWidth="100dp"
                        android:minHeight="100dp"
                        android:scaleType="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/slider_place_holder" />

                     </RelativeLayout>

                     <!-- some other layouts -->


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

I have tired a custom drawable and wrapping it around ImageView using a FrameLayout but it isn't working as expected.
